# Codeigniter and Percent Sign in URL, again

Tags: codeigniter

I understand that Codeigniter has built in security that will url decode a URL before it checks on whitelisted special characters. For example, if I have a URL containing %3d, Codeigniter decodes to an = sign, then checks if = is whitelisted.

But what if I need to pass %3d just as is, without it being decoded and then compared to a whitelist, except where I have whitelisted a % sign? I just want to pass in %3d and get %3d back, without having to add = to my white list. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The CodeIgniter checks if the value of a key has permitted characters, and you can configure this with the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`, but the error message you get is about the key itself not about its value. The `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` doesn't help you to allow the `%` symbol in this case.

You will find the function `function _clean_input_keys($str)` that checks the keys in `system/core/input.php` (Line 727). The `%` character is not allowed so `'%40'` will not pass:

```
 if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

The only way around this in your case is to avoid this character in key parameters.

Comment: I ended up passing it as a query string param, which allows me more flexibility. I guess I'm not 100% sure what you mean about the key being in violation, not the value. The URI looks like this: /foo/bar/xyz%3d/. The 3rd param is xyz%3d, which is the value, and this is causing the issue, since CI makes it an = sign then checks the allowable whitelist.

Comment: @drpudding if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you